# Sorting 4 Keys of Excel file

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

There is a requirement of 4 key fields to be sorted in Excel file (2013). Given below is the code. But not getting the desired results. Need your help to resolve the issue.

```
Sub ToSortFile()
    Dim lastRow, LastCol As Long

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set source_data = Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(lastRow, LastCol))
    Set Ws = Sheets("Details")
    With Ws.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Ws.Range("B3"), Order:=xlAscending
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Ws.Range("C3"), Order:=xlAscending
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Ws.Range("K3"), Order:=xlAscending
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Ws.Range("M3"), Order:=xlAscending
        .SetRange Ws.Range("B3:U" & lastRow)
        .Header = xlYes
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: "not getting the desired results" meaning what **exactly**? If row 2 is your header, you should include that in the `setrange`.

Comment: The code runs without error. But sorting is not happening or rows are not sorted in the desired order.  row 2 is header. Other wise is the code is correct for sorting. Please guide. thanks in advance.

Comment: Your lastRow code is working on the currently active sheet - presumably it should be working on the Details sheet.

Comment: It is not sorting the excel file and that is why I raised this query. Is there any wrong in the code given and why this is not working. Need help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sort a Range

- Using `Option Explicit` will force you to declare all variables (`Dim ws As Worksheet`, `Dim source_data As Range`).

---

- Declaring variables in one line is not recommended but if you can't help it you need to do it properly:

  ```
  Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long, i As Long, Num As Double
  ```

  because in `Dim lastRow, LastCol As Long`, `LastRow` is declared `As Variant`.

---

- When you write `Set ws = Sheets("Details")`, `Sheets` is not qualified i.e. it refers to the active workbook (`ActiveWorkbook`), the workbook you're looking at which may be the correct workbook or it may not.
- If the worksheet you're working with is in the **workbook containing the code**, then you want to qualify it by using `ThisWorkbook`:

  ```
  Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Details")
  ```
- If it is not, then you want to qualify each worksheet in the following way:

  ```
  Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks("Test.xlsx")
  ```

  or if the workbook is closed, to open it ...

  ```
  Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Test\Test.xlsx")
  ```

  ... and continue with...

  ```
  Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Details")
  ```
- Note that there are cases when you have to use `ActiveWorkbook`.

---

- When you write `lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row`, `Cells` and `Rows` are not qualified i.e. they refer to the active sheet (`ActiveSheet`) which may be worksheet `Details` or it may not.
- To qualify it you can use the following:

  ```
  Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Details")
  Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
  ```

---

- A rule of thumb is to be explicit as often as possible (reasonable) i.e. don't let Excel decide for you.
- You won't use `.Header = xlGuess` but you will use `xlYes` when the range includes the headers or `xlNo` when it doesn't. In your particular case, you were referencing only the data (`Ws.Range("B3:U" & lastRow)`) i.e. it didn't include the headers so you should have used `xlNo`.
- Related to the `Keys` argument, although it is enough to specify any cell within the column to be sorted, I would recommend specifying the whole column i.e. instead of `B2` use `B2:BLastRow`, `2` being the header row.

---

- Note that the sorting is performed in the order from the last added sort field to the first i.e. in your case the order is `M`, `K`, `C`, and `B` i.e. it still could be wrong for you.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ToSortFile()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Details")
    
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim LastCol As Long
    LastCol = ws.Cells(2, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = ws.Range("B2", ws.Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
    
    With ws.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=srg.Columns(1), Order:=xlAscending
        .SortFields.Add Key:=srg.Columns(2), Order:=xlAscending
        .SortFields.Add Key:=srg.Columns(10), Order:=xlAscending
        .SortFields.Add Key:=srg.Columns(12), Order:=xlAscending
        .SetRange srg
        .Header = xlYes
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot & Fantastic. Working fine. Thanks for your valuable guidance.